# Linear algebra in keras layer

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, scipy

I'm trying to implement the `scipy.lingalg.null_space` module as a Lambda layer in `keras`. 
My input is in the form of batches of `numpy` arrays of shape `(5,5)`, but a simple

```
def ns(x_array):
    x_array = np.array(x_array)
    return null_space(x_array)

null = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: ns(x) )(input)
```

yields the error message:

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py in null_space(A, rcond)
    382 
    383     """
--> 384     u, s, vh = svd(A, full_matrices=True)
    385     M, N = u.shape[0], vh.shape[1]
    386     if rcond is None:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py in svd(a, full_matrices, compute_uv, overwrite_a, check_finite, lapack_driver)
    107 
    108     """
--> 109     a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
    110     if len(a1.shape) != 2:
    111         raise ValueError('expected matrix')

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py in _asarray_validated(a, check_finite, sparse_ok, objects_ok, mask_ok, as_inexact)
    240     if not objects_ok:
    241         if a.dtype is np.dtype('O'):
--> 242             raise ValueError('object arrays are not supported')
    243     if as_inexact:
    244         if not np.issubdtype(a.dtype, np.inexact):

ValueError: object arrays are not supported
```

I think I have to force the input to `null_space`  to be a 2-dimensional array (rather than the 3-dimensional shape of each batch) but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: If you are using this as part of a neural network, you cannot user numpy in a Lambda layer, because you cannot differentiate through numpy with keras/tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

You can re-implement the `null_space` with keras/tensorflow. Refer to the scipy source https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py#L333-L391

The implementation looks straightforward. You will have to use svd, though, so you can use [tf.linalg.svd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/svd).

---

Edit: I typically don't do this, but I was curious, so here is a tensorflow implementation of `null_space`. The outputs are close to but not exactly equal to those of scipy.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

float32_eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps

def tf_null_space(A, rcond=None):
    s, u, vh = tf.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=True)
    vh = tf.transpose(vh)
    M, N = u.shape[0], vh.shape[1]
    if rcond is None:
        rcond = float32_eps * max(M, N)
    tol = tf.reduce_max(s) * rcond
    num = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(s > tol, tf.int32))
    Q = tf.math.conj(tf.transpose(vh[num:, :]))
    return Q
```

Comment: I take it you mean copying the `null_space` definition and essentially replacing `np` with `tf`? Sounds reasonable

Comment: More or less. But you will have to figure out how to take care of the `np.finfo` call. You can assume an input dtype, like float32, and store the eps of that as a constant.

Comment: Coming back to this, my problem now is counting the number of singular values less than the tolerance, and using this number to extract the correct columns of `v` provided by `tf.linalg.svd` ...

Comment: @nonreligious - please see my updated answer. it should answer your question

Comment: Thanks very much @jakub but I'm still finding a few bugs in this (I had tried something similar earlier) - first the `rcond` definition screws up (fixed by removing max(M,N) ):
`<ipython-input-32-1af918f7200e> in tf_null_space(A, rcond)
     28     M, N = u.shape[0], vh.shape[1]
     29     if rcond is None:
---> 30         rcond = float32_eps * max(M, N)
     31     tol = tf.reduce_max(s) * rcond
     32     num = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(s > tol, tf.int32))
...
    411 
    412   def __floordiv__(self, other):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Dimension' and 'float' `

Comment: Once I do my fix on this, I get an error saying `
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to 'Dense' should be defined. Found 'None' `  - specifying the `output_shape` in the layer does not fix this. I'd be curious to see how you implemented this in an actual network.